# Inserting incremental values into loop array

Tags: javascript

Right now I am animating an image by stringing multiple images together with `setInterval(showNextSlide, 100);` and it works really well.

The only thing that I'm running into problems with is adding values dynamically into `var slides = [src, ]` the while loop just loads the final image.

Also the way the images are saved the increment moves to the next zero so `01009` converts to `01010` whenever I use my loop it will convert to `010010` note the extra zero at the end.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var img = 0
  while (img < 15) {
    img++;
  }
  var src = 'assets/images/earth/Sequence%0100' + img + '.jpg.';
  var slides = [src, ],
    index = 0,
    timer = 0;

  // Show the first slide
  showNextSlide();

  // Show "next" slide every five seconds
  timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 100);

  // The function we call to show the "next" slide    
  function showNextSlide() {
    if (index >= slides.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('earth').src = slides[index++];
  }
};
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLzywnmq/)

Comment: Why don't you make your images as one sprite image containing whole set of smaller images and just offset it's `x` or `y` by its width or height respectively, thus you reduce your http request to the minimum and you won't end up the final image only

Comment: there is like 200 images:(  @JEES and the file would be way to big

Comment: it is ok and the file size is almost the same as the whole set of the small images, but with only 1 http request instead of 200

Comment: http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/06/04/animating-a-css-sprite-with-javascript/

Comment: Not really looking to do a sprite though

Comment: Try `var slides = [],
    i = 0,
    noOfImages = 200;

while(i < noOfImages) slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%0100' + i++ + '.jpg');`

Comment: @Tushar, this wouldn't solve the `01009` will turn to `010010`

Comment: @NooBskie Can you please add the sample image numbers

Comment: Yea ill make a codepen

Comment: @NooBskie I prefer jsfiddle :P

Comment: `var img = (i < 10) ?  '0100' + i++ : '010' + i++; slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%' + img + '.jpg');`

Comment: What about `var slides = [],
    i = 0,
    noOfImages = 200;

while (slides.length < noOfImages) {
    if (i % 9 === 0) continue;
    slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%0100' + i++ + '.jpg');
}`, skipping the divisibles of 9. OR `var slides = [],
    i = 0,
    noOfImages = 200;

while (slides.length < noOfImages) {
    if (i % 10 === 9) continue;
    slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%0100' + i++ + '.jpg');
}` skipping if the remainder after division by 10 is 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:It will keep on changing the image src of earth based on the index value.

*Update based on JEES Comment.*

```
<script>

  window.onload = function() {
       var i = 0

  var slides = [];
  while (i < 200) {

      if(i <= 9){ img= '0100' + i++; }
      else if(i <= 99){ img= '010' + i++; }  
      else{ img= '01' + i++; }  
      var src = 'assets/images/earth/Sequence%' + img + '.jpg';
      slides.push(src);    
    }

        console.log(slides);
        index = 0,
        timer = 0;

      // Show the first slide
      showNextSlide();

      // Show "next" slide every five seconds
      timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 100);

      // The function we call to show the "next" slide    
      function showNextSlide() {
        if (index >= slides.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('earth').src = slides[index++];
      }
    };
</script>
<img src="" id="earth">
```

Comment: This works well but what about when it goes past 10?

Comment: @Suchit, when img is 01009 the img++ will be `010010 so he needs sme conditional statement to solve it.

Comment: something like this `var img = (i < 10) ? '0100' + i++ : '010' + i++; slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%' + img + '.jpg');`

Comment: he will need a similar fix when `img = 9` and `img = 99` considering the number of images is 200

Comment: "0000".substr(num.toString().length)+num is a simpler way to add padding to a number.

Comment: This one is still adding an extra number on the end with the edit:( `010121`

Comment: Actually this code will print `0109.jpg` instead of `01009.jpg`, to fix this make the first condition  `if(i < 10)` or `if(i <= 9)`

Answer (score 1):

Please Try It :

```
var img = 0;

var slides = new Array(); 

while (img < 5) {

img++;

var src = 'assets/images/earth/Sequence%0100' + img + '.jpg';

slides.push(src);

}
```

Comment: This still wont solve the second problem of this post

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the answer and it will fix it when `img` value is `9` or `99` since he has 200 images, if images number > 1000 he'd need another one when `img` value `999`.. please tell me if i should delete this answer:

**UPDATED:**

```
 var img = 0;
 while(img < 200) {
    if (img < 10) { imgURL = '0100' + img; }
    else if (img < 100) { imgURL = '010' + img;}
    else { imgURL = '01' + img; }
    slides.push('assets/images/earth/Sequence%' + imgURL + '.jpg');
    img++;
}
```

check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/07rj4haL/3/) to see it in action..

Comment: Just post the full code if you could so i know which answer to accept

Comment: accept his answer and modify your code including this one, or he might modify his answer so that you accept it

Comment: @NooBskie, I've updated this snippet and it is working now

Comment: Now the `while` works, my fault i didn't set `img = 0` before it!